# Server apache reverse does not encode coma in UTF-8

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, encoding, utf-8, charset

Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built: Nov 5 2018 01:47:09
centos-release-7-6.1810.2.el7.centos.x86_64

We are trying to solve a reverse problem and we need you help
Reverse proxy Apache should send a %2C in url but instead send a classic comma , other lines without comma are OK.

example

attended by software :
GET /xxxx/rest/typevt/contexte/actif/INDORI%2CACTREAL%2Cnull HTTP/2.0 200 15

instead
GET /xxxx/rest/typevt/contexte/actif/INDORI,ACTREAL,null HTTP/1.1 404

configuration is :

## Ecoute en HTTP -> Redirection vers HTTPS

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName xxxxx.xxx.fr

## Redirection des requetes HTTP to HTTPS

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

## Logging

ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/xxxxxx/error_http.log
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/xxxxxxxx/access_http.log common

ProxyRequests off

## Ecoute en HTTPS

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName xxxxxx.xxxxx.fr
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

#Supression double slash
DirectorySlash Off

## SSL

SSLEngine on
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!ADH:!DH:!RC4
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCertificateFile      /etc/httpd/certificat/xxxxxxx.fr/certif.xxxxxxx.fr.cer
SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/httpd/certificat/xxxxxxxxx.fr/wild.xxxxxxx.fr.rsa.pkey
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/certificat/xxxxxxxxx.fr/Certif_intermediaire.cer

ProxyPass / https://xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.fr/
ProxyPassReverse / https://xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.fr/

## Logging

ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/xxxxxxxx/error_https.log
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/xxxxxxxxxxxx/access_https.log common

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyVia Off